# Spring MVC similar setters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two classes with a `String title` field. They have similar setters called `setTitle()`. When I use them as object parameters in a POST request, the field values rewrite to new values in Foo and Bar. Foo populates in `Controller` before request.

```
public class Foo{
  // ...
  String title;

  public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title=title;
    // ...
  }

public class Bar {
  // ...
  String title;

  public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title=title;
    // ...
  }
}

@ModelAttribute 
public void populateFoo(Model model){
  Foo foo = Foo.getFromDb() 

  model.addAttribute(foo);
}

@RequestMapping
public String somePost(Foo foo, Bar bar, ...){
  Bar newBar = new Bar();
  newBar.setTitle(bar.getTitle());
}
```

When I'm invoking `setTitle()` on `newBar`, method `setTitle()` on `Foo` also invoked.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You're trying to set both Foo and Bar's setTitle()?

Comment: You need to show your view code from which you are posting.

Comment: Please include your code for `Controller` and `Foo` and `Bar` and `Model`. Also, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: They're not *similar*, they're **identical**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way for Spring MVC to distinguish unfortunately - if you submit a field with name `title` then all complex types which have a setter for `title` will get set. This is probably one place where a DTO may help, a type which encompasses fields from both types and then instantiates `Foo` OR `Bar` appropriately.

Comment: Why this is happen? I use two different classes and don't understand this.

Comment: Because Spring ultimately binds by field name - since both your `Foo` and `Bar` types have a field called `title` both would be bound, there is absolutely no way for Spring to distinguish that one setTitle is different from the other setTitle..one more possible workaround could be to name the field in the non-relevant class a little different.

Comment: could you provide DTO example similar to my classes?